# How to covert a war file (having persistance.xml and entity.java class packaged within it) into an ear file?

Tags: java

I am trying to package a war file to a ear file as i have to deploy my project on webLogic. I have created a dynamic web project which has 1 entity (java class)class and 1 persistance.xml (and lot of other lib files, jsp files,java classes). I have extracted this project as a war file. Now to deploy it on weblogic I need to have a ear file. I dont know how to do it...when i simply added my war file as a web module in ear I got a null pointer exception. I believe I need to do something with persistance.xml and entity files. Please help.

When I was running dynamic web project on my local tomcat it was running fine and persistance.xml was placed in src/metainf folder and looks like this:

```
 persistence-unit name="MyWar"

 class PackageName.MyEntity class

properties
  property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
 property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:XYZ"/>
 property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="USERNAME"/>
 property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD"/>
  property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
 property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
 properties

 persistence-unit

 persistence    `
```

For placing project on web logic I am using JTA.My persistance.xml is in src/metaInf and looks like this.

```
  persistence-unit name="MyWar" transaction-type="JTA"

    jta-data-source XYZ.datasource /jta-data-source

     class packageName.MyEntity class

   <exclude-unlisted-classes>false exclude-unlisted-classes> 

    persistence-unit

  persistence
```

I extracted dynamic web project as a WAR and added it in EA project

My application.xml (in EA project) is placed in EARContent/MetaInf/application.xml and looks like this:

```
        display-name EARName display-name

       module

        web 

          web-uri MyWar.war  web-uri

           context-root MyWar context-root 

       web

       module

    application
```

Extracted a EAR and placed in webLogic server.
Error:

Nov 24, 2014 12:04:19 PM GMT Error HTTP BEA-101371 There was a failure when processing annotations for application /opt/dap/domains/PORTALINSTANCE/int/domain/servers/MS1/tmp/_WL_user/MYWARNAME/48n279/MYWARNAME.war. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is null.

I am first time writting my question , please excuse my way of writting code.

Comment: you can deploy a .war file into an EE container.  the only advantage of repackaging as an .ear file is that you get to bundle multiple .war files as well as service endpoint ejb-jar files (remote ejbs).

Comment: Do I need to do anything extra with persistance.xml file? or the entity.java class?

Comment: What about persistance.xml and entity.java class?

Comment: persistence.xml would reside where your ORM/DAO layer resides (in the META-INF dir of your war file or in the ejb jar file if you split out the ejb layer from the war file [assuming you go .ear])  the entities would either be in the WEB-INF/classes dir if you go with war packaging or in your ejb jar file if you split it out and deploy as an .ear file.

Comment: My entity lies in src folder (war)...is that the problem?

Comment: When i try to deploy I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Error :
Nov 24, 2014 12:04:19 PM GMT Error HTTP BEA-101371 There was a failure when processing annotations for application /opt/dap/domains/PORTALINSTANCE/int/domain/servers/MS1/tmp/_WL_user/MYWARNAME/48n279/MYWARNAME.war. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is null.

Comment: Is it necessary to split and deploy (ear) . Simply adding the war file as an web module in ear will not do?

Comment: you can, but there is no reason to.  the only reason to deploy as an .ear is if you want to split the layers into different deployable modules (war, jar, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy a .war file into an EE container. the only advantage of repackaging as an .ear file is that you get to bundle multiple .war files as well as service endpoint ejb-jar files (remote ejbs).

persistence.xml would reside where your ORM/DAO layer resides (in the META-INF dir of your war file or in the ejb jar file if you split out the ejb layer from the war file [assuming you go .ear]) the entities would either be in the WEB-INF/classes dir if you go with war packaging or in your ejb jar file if you split it out and deploy as an .ear file.